# Make a list with JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Program is suppose to ask user to enter a to do item to a list or enter "quit" to quit and exit out of the loop. Subfunction asks for the input and adds to the list. Main function outputs the list from JS to HTML.

To me it appears to look right but as I'm still learning, not sure why it is stuck in infinite loop of prompting for input even when entering "quit". Any help appreciated!

```
//global variables
var output;
var input;


function buildList(input) {
    "use strict";

    // declare variables
    var unorderedList;
    var inputList;

    input = prompt("Enter a to-do item or \"quit\" to stop: ");

    unorderedList = document.getElementById("toDo");

    inputList += "<li>" + input + "</li>";

    unorderedList.innerHTML = inputList;
}


function outputList() {
    "use strict";

    // PART 1: YOUR CODE STARTS AFTER THIS LINE
    // declare constants
    const QUIT_CODE = "quit";

    // declare variables
    var output;

    while (input !== QUIT_CODE) {
        buildList();
        output = document.getElementById("outputPart1");
        output.innerHTML += input;
        if (input === QUIT_CODE) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // end of code
}
```

Comment: Please log the value of input inside while loop and see what you are getting. Also if is not required inside while loop, it will automatically exit the loop if input is same as QUIT_CODE.

Comment: I would do something if you post the HTML code also and the code that you have tried!

Comment: The issue is the scope of `input`. You have `input` which is a global variable, and you have `input` which is a parameter to `buildList`. When you call `buildList()`, you only change the `input` inside the `buildList` function, not the global variable. Are you only allowed to  change code in `outputList()`?

Comment: Try calling buildList with the global variable, like this: `buildList(input)` instead of just `buildList()`

Comment: Just realized that won't work either. It would only work if input was an object that had a property that was changed, instead of being reassigned altogether. The only solutions I see that are left are quite complex, unless you can change `buildList()` to have no arguments.

Comment: @ShamPooSham removing the argument from buildList worked. But now it just doesn't display correctly in the html page.

Comment: Good thing it works :) Btw, please don't change your question to fit the answer, it will make everything confusing for other readers. Now, what's the issue with the html page?

Comment: @ShamPooSham it displays the input but does it only once. It doesn't loop at all to keep asking for more input and adding to the html.

Comment: Alright, I would suggest that you try to figure that out by yourself first, and if you're still stuck you create a new question with both the HTML and JS (creating a jsfiddle isn't bad). When you try to debug it, use `console.log()` and look at the web console.

Answer (score -3):

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <ul id="outputPart1">

      </ul>
      <script>
          var output;
          var input;


          function buildList(input) {
          "use strict";

          // declare variables
          var unorderedList;
          var inputList;

          input = prompt("Enter a to-do item or \"quit\" to stop: ");

          unorderedList = document.getElementById("toDo");

          inputList += "<li>" + input + "</li>";

          unorderedList.innerHTML = inputList;
          }


          function outputList() {
          "use strict";

          // PART 1: YOUR CODE STARTS AFTER THIS LINE
          // declare constants
          const QUIT_CODE = "quit";

          // declare variables
          var output,i=0;
          //input = prompt("Enter a to-do item or \"quit\" to stop: ");
          while (input !== QUIT_CODE) {
              //buildList();
            ++i;
            input = prompt("Enter a to-do item or \"quit\" to stop: ");
              output = document.getElementById("outputPart1");
              output.innerHTML += (i+". "+input+"<br/>");
              if (input === QUIT_CODE) {
                  break;
              }
          }

          // end of code
          }
          outputList();
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code print list. Hope help you

Comment: Code-only answers stating "hope this helps" or the like are never good answers.

Comment: But I answered with my ability. You know the answer better but do you answer that question?

Comment: Why didn't you remove `buildList(input)` completely if you don't even use it anymore?

Comment: For the topic owner to easily see the difference